# Image not fetching from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

```
package com.example.bloomroom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Flowers> list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Flowers> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recylce_item,parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Flowers flowers = list.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(flowers.getName());
        holder.category.setText(flowers.getCategory());
        holder.price.setText(flowers.getPrice());
        Log.d("TestUrl", "onBindViewHolder " + flowers.getFurl());
        Glide.get(context).clearMemory();
        new Thread(() -> Glide.get(context).clearDiskCache()).start();
        Glide.with(holder.imgView.getContext())
                .load(flowers.getFurl())
                .into(holder.imgView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView name, category, price;
        ImageView imgView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            category=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCat);
            price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            imgView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fetch some data from a Realtime Firebase Database. All string values fetched, but the image is not coming on android app.
I tried some log methods that show the url, but the file is not loading inside the application.

I have already enabled the Internet access on manifest.

[Log screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g99Gd.png)

Comment: Instead of adding an incomplete picture, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, please also show the part of the code where you're getting data from Firebase. Only the adapter is not enough.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.